# Why does 'gem install compass' work but 'gem install compass --pre' doesn't?

Tags: ruby, terminal, sass, compass-sass, susy-compass

So I began a project at work working with Compass & Susy. Everything worked fine on the iMac there, and I wanted to transfer the files to my laptop to do some work from home. I took the files from FTP and then tried to run a `compass watch` on the directory but was getting errors bc Susy was not installed. So I install Susy. Then I try to watch again and I get the error:

```
Gem::ConflictError on line ["2099"] of /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb: Unable to activate susy-2.1.3, because sass-3.2.19 conflicts with sass (< 3.5, >= 3.3.0)
```

So, I'm like, okay, this shouldn't be that hard to fix. Googling around and everyone says to `gem install compass --pre`. I'm like, okay, I will do that. I get errors out the ass. I tried downloading xcode command line tools, rvm requirements, and nothing is really working for me. The error output code is this:

```
             Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
            /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:73: warning: Insecure world writable dir /Users/jaylaiche/.rvm in PATH, mode 040777
            ERROR:  Error installing compass:
                ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

                /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20140729-74623-1y0hghc.rb extconf.rb
            /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:1500: warning: Insecure world writable dir /Users/jaylaiche/.rvm in PATH, mode 040777
            checking for ffi.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***
            Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
            libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
            need configuration options.

            Provided configuration options:
                --with-opt-dir
                --without-opt-dir
                --with-opt-include
                --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
                --with-opt-lib
                --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
                --with-make-prog
                --without-make-prog
                --srcdir=.
                --curdir
                --ruby=/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby
                --with-ffi_c-dir
                --without-ffi_c-dir
                --with-ffi_c-include
                --without-ffi_c-include=${ffi_c-dir}/include
                --with-ffi_c-lib
                --without-ffi_c-lib=${ffi_c-dir}/
                --with-libffi-config
                --without-libffi-config
                --with-pkg-config
                --without-pkg-config
            /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:434:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
            You have to install development tools first.
                from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:549:in `block in try_compile'
                from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:502:in `with_werror'
                from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:549:in `try_compile'
                from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:1044:in `block in have_header'
                from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:895:in `block in checking_for'
                from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:340:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
                from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:310:in `open'
                from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:340:in `block in postpone'
                from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:310:in `open'
                from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:336:in `postpone'
                from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:894:in `checking_for'
                from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:1043:in `have_header'
                from extconf.rb:16:in `<main>'

            extconf failed, exit code 1

            Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/ffi-1.9.3 for inspection.
            Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/extensions/universal-darwin-13/2.0.0/ffi-1.9.3/gem_make.out
```

I tried navigating to the log running `emacs ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/compass/ext/mkmf.log` but nothing.

Can anyone save my soul? And explain what is going on here? I would like to understand so that I don't run into this problem again. I just don't see a simple explanation for this occurrence, especially considering I can 'gem install compass' fine, but 'gem install compass --pre' won't work. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `brew install apple-gcc42` before installing the gem with `--pre`.

Comment: I ran that command successfully but `gem install compass --pre` still gives me the same error as above.